# Urban Airship alias and tags

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

Thanks for previous replies,

How do we set the alias and tag in device token via program. I have referred airship doc, i find out we can set alias and tag using setAliasandTags function, can anyone guide me how to do this in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to set alias and tags on Android:

```
// Alias    
PushManager.shared().setAlias("alias");

// Tags
HashSet<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();
tags.add("tag1");
tags.add("tag2");
PushManager.shared().setTags(tags);
```

I personally call this during the onCreate of the application.